# JavaFx ListView doesn't show text, but working after cellFactory

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a `ListView` with click listener. I want add new listener on hover. I coded that new listener with `CellFactory` (code below). Only with this code my `ListView` (`<String>`) show items without text but both listeners works fine (click listener works fine anyway) and items properly selected.

Code of `CellFactory` in `Controller`'s `initialize()`:

```
myListView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {};
        cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
        if(isNowHovered) {
            handleCellHover(cell);
        } else {
            handleCellHoverEnd();
        }
    });
    return cell;
});
```

Code of adding elements:

```
// ...
ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data); //data is List<String>
listView.setItems(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListCell.updateItem` by default does nothing but assign the `item` and `empty` properties. You need to override this method to use the item for modifying the cell's look, e.g. by setting the `text` property:

```
ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(item);
        }
    }
};
```

*(The default `cellFactory` uses a subclass of `ListCell` with a similar `updateItem` implementation.)*